# Using Hibernate to get the latest row with a LocalDateTime

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, java-8, localdatetime

I have a Java8 application using SpringBoot, which is pulling in Hibernate core 5.3.10 (connected to PostgreSQL 11). A simplified explanation: the application is maintaining a history of changes to a series of bespoke `UserData` records, containing two `LocalDateTime` columns for `startDate` and `endDate`, and a `userId` column (plus other columns).

The semantics of the application are that a history of changes to the `UserData` are maintained by the `start_date` and `end_date` contain no duplicates (respectively), and that any row where the `endDate` is `null` is the currently *active* record for a *user*. (Accordingly, a user may have *no* currently *active* record.)

It is a simple matter to retrieve all of the *active* rows, and this is working well.

However, I have a requirement to retrieve the *latest* row for all *users* irrespective of whether the row is *active* or not.

One way to achieve this outcome using `SQL` is with a query something like the following:

```
select ud1.* from user_data ud1
   where ud1.start_date = (select max(ud2.start_date) from user_data ud2 
                                            where ud2.user_id = ud1.user_id);
```

I have been attempting to write a `CriteriaQuery` to replicate the SQL, but I have run into a data type problem with the `CriteriaBuilder.max` method. The `max` method is complaining that it will only accept a type `Number` column. The code looks like this:

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<UserDate> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(UserData.class);

final Root<UserData> ud1 = criteriaQuery.from(UserData.class);

final Subquery<LocalDateTime> maxUserDataStartDate = criteriaQuery.subquery(LocalDateTime.class);
final Root<UserData> ud2 = maxUserDataStartDate.from(UserData.class);
maxUserDataStartDate.select(builder.max(ud2.get("startDate"));
// ...
```

The problem is with the last line, where it complains that `ud2.get("startDate")` is not an extension of type `Number` - which is true, of course.

Does anybody know how to fix this situation? Especially, does anybody have an example they can share that does what I'm after?

Answer (score 2):

You can do order by `start_date` desc and get top 1

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<UserData> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(UserData.class);

Root<UserData> ud = criteriaQuery.from(UserData.class);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.desc(ud.get("startDate")));
entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getFirstResult();
```

Comment: This is a good idea, thanks. I'll try it out and see where it gets me.

Comment: In the end I went with my original proposal and implemented using HQL using `@Query`, which works fine, albeit with some consideration of reduced IDE refactoring support. Asked a similar question on the Hibernate ORM forums, without any response (to date)
https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/why-does-the-aggregate-max-method-only-extend-number/4407